# Django Admin Page Unavailable in Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, admin

I believe I have all the prerequisites correct to get the admin page to appear, i have double checked with a bunch of other stack overflow posts and cannot figure out my error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

So I have Django setup on my Apache server. I go to `http://localhost/` and i get the IT WORKED! Page. However, as SOON as I uncomment the admin lines in `settings.py` and `urls.py`, I get the Django 404 Error. I think i am doing something wrong with the Aliases and links to the django admin folder. Here is my relevant code

httpd.conf (wsgi loadmodule is included)

```
Alias /media/ "c:/xampp/htdocs/django_ngs/media"
Alias /static/ "c:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
<Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/django_ngs>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/xampp/htdocs/django_ngs/mod.wsgi"
```

settings.py (relevant parts)

```
ADMINS = (
    # ('user', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql',     'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'djangodb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or   '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}


MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you going to /admin in your browser?

Comment: yes. I go to `http://localhost/admin`, but even `http://localhost` breaks when i uncomment the admin portions... which means something trivial is messed up.

Comment: Do I do something with the default `admin` folder in my `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib` directory? I also might need to use the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\static` static folder as well. But I'm not sure where to put them.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that localhost/ on its own would work. You don't have any URLs configured to point to the root, only the /admin/ one.

Comment: So why isn't the /admin/ one working?

Comment: I don't know. What does the error log say? Have you successfully run this locally using the development server?

Comment: Also does not work on development. Error log says 404, and `Using the URLconf defined in django_ngs.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. ^admin/ , 
The current URL, django_ngs/, didn't match any of these.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone also looking for a solution, I found the kink. In urls.py it should have been `url(r'/admin/', include(admin.site.urls))` instead of `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`, (switching the carrot for the forward slash). This was not apparent in all of the other example url.py files I have looked at... Anyway thank you for your attention and attempt to help, i really appreciate your time. Make sure the directory to your admin content is correct!